# Where did the snowflake necklace come from?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

In *Once Upon A Time*, Elsa finds a snowflake necklace in their mother's belongings, and gives it to Anna.

However, we later learn that

> their parents only acquired the necklace while on the journey they never returned from, having bought it from Black Beard.

How did the necklace wind up back in the castle in Arendelle?

Answer (score 2):

Shipping something home, especially before a particularly treacherous leg of a journey, makes sense as a precaution.

It's a *ridiculously* high-magic world, so the shipping could simply be a spell. (The writers ain't shy about using magic as the solution to practically every problem in their plot.) Some wandering magical good-deed-doer could handle the process, or that silly "author" plot, even.

Personally, from what was shown, I figure it could just as easily be a common design that she recognized rather than necessarily the same object. Presumably, she'd consider such a clue that she was on the right track.

They have yet to elaborate on that part, though, which I suspect means they have yet to decide any of this.

Comment: 'I suspect means they have yet to decide any of this.' --> And they never will?

Comment: Maybe in a year or so when they are flailing about seeking details for some continuity porn they'll be all "ooh, we left that unexplained. If we explain it now, it'll look like great long-term planning."

Comment: HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA